# Why is count correctly incremented

Tags: javascript

Consider this simple example:

```
var count = 0;
for (var i = 0; i < 4; i++ ) {
    setTimeout(function() {
      console.log(i, count++);
    }, i * 200);
}
```

which outputs the following

```
4 0
4 1
4 2
4 3
```

I would guess that `i` always resolves to 4 because the setTimeout callback closes over the variable I but I can't figure out why the same doesn't hold true for `count`?

```js
var count = 0;
for (var i = 0; i < 4; i++ ) {
  setTimeout(function() {
    console.log(i, count++);
  }, i * 2000 );
}
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The variable `i` is incremented by your `for` loop, and ends up with the value `4` *before* any of the timeout handlers run. The variable `count`, on the other hand, is only incremented *inside* the timeout handlers. When the first timeout handler fires, `count` will still be `0`.

Answer (score 2):

As the lads before me said, It's because the loop completes before the timeout is activated.

One way around this would be to put your timeout in a different function, and pass the `i` to it from within the loop. This ensures that for each iteration, the function is passed the correct `i`

This is also why `count` is set to the expected value; it lies outside of the loop's scope.

```
for (var i = 0; i < 4; i++) {
    doSomething(i);
};
function doSomething(i) {
    setTimeout(function() {
        console.log(i);
    }, i * 2000);
};
```